# Seeking QGIS 3.0 ways to create browser based 3D scenes like qgis2threejs plugin does?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis-3, qgis2threejs

I want to create a browser-based 3D scenes and use Github to share it. However, the qgis2threejs plugin is not available in QGIS 3.

Is there any alternative way to create similar browser-based 3D scenes?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the long term support release of QGIS 2.18 instead of the non-LTR QGIS 3.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Qgis2threejs is available under QGIS 3.2 but the icon changed from the one exists in QGIS 2.18:

[image]

In Qgis 3.2 it is called Qgis2threejs Exporter, and you can use it to create a 3D scene in browswer:

[image]